# Monodevelop Proxy Settings

Tags: .net, proxy, mono, network-programming, monodevelop

How do I set the proxy settings of Monodevelop? I tried to modify the Monodevelop.exe.config with the following code

```
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
            <proxy
                proxyaddress = "http://172.0.0.18:8080"
                bypassonlocal = "true"/>
        </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

But its not taking `useDefaultCredentials="true"` attribute, it is saying  **Unrecognized attribute 'useDefaultCredentials'** in the exception box. Moreover my proxy settings need userid and password and this credential is different from Windows Logon credentials. So how do I specify those for Monodevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as configuring the proxy for any .NET app. IIRC, if autodetection is enabled, then .NET will use the WinHTTP proxy settings, which are set through IE or proxycfg.exe.

Re. your main question, the [useDefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwyc043.aspx) attribute should on the `<proxy>` element, not the `<defaultProxy>` element.